Laravel Socialite Azure B2C Login
Can anyone please give me a hint how to use Laravel/Socialite Azure B2C for login with multitenant and personal accounts. Login with multitenant works perfect but when i use personal email, I'm redirected to /login with error.
I have setup the code for login with organization email and works,but i cannot reset the password when try to login with personal email.i want to use both organization and personal email for login, for this purpose i added ['tenant' => env('AD_TENANT_ID', 'common')], on services at:
'azureadb2c' => [
    'client_id' => env('AADB2C_ClientId'),
    'client_secret' => env('AADB2C_ClientSecret'),
    'redirect' => env('AADB2C_RedirectUri'),
    'domain' => env('AADB2C_Domain'),
    'policy' => env('AADB2C_Policy'),
    'default_algorithm' => env('AADB2C_DefaultAlgorithm', 'RS256'),
    ['tenant' => env('AADB2C_TENANT', 'common')],
    'password_reset_policy' => env('AADB2C_PasswordResetPolicy'),
],

when i try to reset the password for login with personal email i get redirected to /login with error message

Can you include the error?
